# StringUtils.contains of Apache and Boyer–Moore string search algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, boyer-moore

To search for s in S  (size(S) >= size(s) and return a true/false value), it's better for performance to use StringUtils.contains() of Apache or use Boyer-Moore algorithm implemented and tested well by someone I found?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last time I looked into the Java regex matching code while debugging, the Java 7 regex engine used the Boyer-Moore algorithm for sequences of literal text matches. So the easiest way to find a `String` using Boyer-Moore is to prepare using `p=Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL)` and search using `p.matcher(toSearchOn).find()`. No third party libraries and no handcrafted work needed. And I believe the JRE classes are tested well…

Answer (score 0):

Apache Lang uses the Java API's Region Matching for their contains implementation. Hard to say which is faster on the surface.  Sounds like an opportunity to build a simple test case and run it both ways and see.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Sorry I'm not reputation enough to vote for your answer.

Comment: If you're going to do performance testing in this style, it's a good idea to use a framework, such as [OpenJDK JMH] http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/